# Use terminal to access dir/file that's been installed via SMB?

Tags: ubuntu, server-message-block

I'm using Ubuntu on my computer.  On my desktop, I see a folder that says 'web on 10.100.10.28'.    When I try to overwrite a file, I get a good warning 'The file already exists in `smb://john@10.100.10.28/web/sites/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/Simplism`.  Replacing it will overwrite its content.'

I want to use the vi editor via terminal to edit the file `smb://john@10.100.10.28/web/sites/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/Simplism/index.html`.  But when I type

```
vi smb://john@10.100.10.28/web/sites/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/Simplism/index.html
```

then add some content and try to save, the terminal tells me I am unable to save.  What's wrong with what I'm doing?  And how come I can't do this?

```
cd smb://john@10.100.10.28/web/sites/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/Simplism
```

I looked in /dev, /media and /mount, but don't see how to go to that directory

Answer (score 1):

You can try to mount the smb location using the mount command. 
Using:

```
mount -t smbfs -o username=username,password=pwd //shared/ destination
```

or

```
mount -t cifs -o username=username,password=pwd //shared/ destination
```

(the command depends on your os version)

and then try to edit a file with vi.

And: are you sure you have write access to that folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you've contacted the server with gnome, it's already mounted in your home directory.

```
# vi ~/.gvfs/web\ on\ 10.100.10.28/sites/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/Simplism/index.html
```

will probably work.